ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.oauth2'
I wanted to clone https://github.com/theevann/meditator (a streamlit app) but when I try to run it, it gives me an error as ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.oauth2'. Here is the traceback:

File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\streamlitenv\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\hibap\meditator\meditator.py", line 10, in <module>
from voice_synthesis import synthesize_ssml, get_voice_list
File "C:\Users\hibap\meditator\voice_synthesis.py", line 2, in <module>
from google.oauth2 import service_account


Just in case you need this info : I installed the packages in requirements.txt and use Anaconda venv. I am new to this coding world so can someone guide me through this problem?

have you run it with this command streamlit run meditator.py your error looks like you're trying to run a python script.

The error message suggests that the google.oauth2 module is not found. This module is part of the google-auth library in Python. You can install it using pip, which is a package manager for Python.
You can install the google-auth library by running the following command in your terminal:
pip3 install google-auth

If you're using an environment (like conda or venv), make sure to activate the environment first before installing the package. If the problem persists after installation, it might be an issue with your Python environment setup. You might have multiple Python installations and pip might be installing the package in a different Python installation than the one you're using to run your script.
